# How to get anchor text in a Session variable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a project in which i have linked many pdf files in the master page.On clicking the anchor the page redirected to the specified page and displays pdf in iframe.Now i want the text in anchor tag to be displayed on the page where pdf is opened.
Consider I have an anchor which looks like this :

```
<a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Main_Content.aspx?open=Departments/HR/NewsLetter/newsletter_dec_2014.pdf">News Letter</a>
```

Now i want the text " News letter" to be shown on the redirected page.
I think i could this by saving the text in session variable.But How can I save the anchor text in Session variable without specifying any id or class to the anchor tag? Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Why you need id or class to put anchor text in session?

Comment: i don't need id or class i just want the anchor text to be saved in session variable when anchor is clicked :)

Comment: I think @Adil's solution is perfect.

Comment: no, it's not helpful for me in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
if($(this).attr("href").match(".pdf$"))
{
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "&title=" + $(this).text();
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

On server side in "Main_Content.aspx"

```
strTitle = Request.QueryString["title"];
```

Comment: thank you so much,it solved my problem.it's the very cool solution for this problem without modifying the anchor or any tag thank you so much :) :) :)

Comment: I'll support your answer (y) support from me :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably looking for QueryString instead of session, You are already passing path in [QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx), also pass the anchor text. You need to add this to url while you are creating the anchor tag.

```
<a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Main_Content.aspx?open=Departments/HR/NewsLetter/newsletter_dec_2014.pdf&aText=News Letter">News Letter</a>
```

On server side

```
lblForAnchor.Text = Request.QueryString["aText"].ToString();
```

**Edit** you can not change the query string when it is created then you can change it when it is loaded in DOM in `document.ready`. Assign a class to your anchors to be specific.

```
$( 'a.someclass' ).attr( 'href', function(index, value) {
  return value + '&aText=' + $(this).text();
});
```

Other way to do this on click of anchor.

```
$( 'a.someclass' ),click(function(event) {
    window.location.href = this.href +  '&aText=' + $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: No,i don't want to add this  in query string because there are hundreds of files  linked so i can't change them all,suggest me do it with javascript or jquery or any trick  :)

Comment: not got the value in query string i used this :  $('a.sendtext'), click(function (event) { and <a class="sendtext" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Main_Content.aspx?open=Departments/HR/NewsLetter/newsletter_dec_2014.pdf">Reach News Letter</a>

Comment: Did you assign class to anchor tag and used the last two solutions?

Comment: No,i didn't assign any class i just used the solution above which is marked as answer :)

Comment: If you do not assign the class it will apply to all anchor on the page. It might be correct today but may be a problem tomorrow. We must be specific while change DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could Write the content dynamically with javascript:

```
<a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %Main_Content.aspx?open=Departments/HR/NewsLetter/newsletter_dec_2014.pdf">News Letter</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function openWin(t,u) {
docstring='<iframe src='+u+'></iframe>';
win = window.open();
newdoc=win.document;
newdoc.writeln(t);
newdoc.write(docstring);
newdoc.close();
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
elements[i].onclick = function () {

var theAnchor = elements[i].innerHTML;
var theHref = elements[i].href;    

 if(theHref.match(/\.pdf/)){
  openWin(theAnchor,theHref);
 }
}
</script>
```

Or call a different address with URL and test as parameters and generate the doc on the server side.

I'm not sure how this will behave with the link click but it might be worth a shot.

links should not have to be modified.

Comment: text, not test. sorry

Comment: Sir actually the problem is that there are many files linked in the project and I ca't update the anchor tag in the complete project but i would support your answer thanks... support from me :)

Comment: updated so href is left alone. no way to do this without modifying links in some way, adding onclick event, adding id, adding class. otherwise adding event listener for all links would create big problems.