# How to know that the anchor was on text or image?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I was suffering from the problem of getting anchor text and print it on the redirected screen in my question:
[How to get anchor text in a Session variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129415/how-to-get-anchor-text-in-a-session-variable)
I got the solution from this question but now if the anchor is on the image,How can i pass some text with it to print it on the redirected page ?
Someone Kindly review the question above in link and help me please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-` attributes:

```
<a class="customLink" href="your/url" data-text="yourText"><img src=".." alt=".." /></a>
```

and send the url with the text from the `data-text` attribute:

```
$(document).on('click', '.customLink', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var that = $(this);
   var url = that.attr('href');
   var text = that.attr('data-text');
   // Continue here ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is `<a><img src="sample.jpg"></a>` right. pass some title using `window.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "&title=" + $(this).text();` and print title as

```
var a = window.location.href.split('&')  
var print = a[a.length - 1]
console.log(print)
```

Hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: I've got the answer.. but i'll support your answer :) support from me

Comment: ok fine. but answer which i have provided is right. its working for me

Comment: I know that it's also fine that's why i voted dear but before you i've got the answer.